# Play Json Validation is failing on Date field with Error: [error.expected.date.isoformat]

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have a `JsonValidationError`.

This is my model:

```
case class Account(id: Long, name: String, birthDate: LocalDate)
object Account {
  implicit val accountFormat = Json.format[Account]
}
```

And this is part of my controller action:

```
def updateProfile = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  val res = request.body.validate[Account]
  logger.info(request.body.toString)
  logger.info(res.toString)

  ...
}
```

I have this output:

```
[info] c.a.AccountController - {"id":1,"name":"John","birthDate":"1983-02-11T23:00:00.000Z"}
[info] c.a.AccountController - JsError(List((/birthDate,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.date.isoformat),ArraySeq(ParseCaseSensitive(false)(Value(Year,4,10,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2))[Offset(+HH:MM:ss,'Z')])))))
```

The data coming from the client seems to be valid, I don't understand that Error, I think the `birthDate` is in the `isoFormat`, so what can be the issue here ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input has a different format than expected for `java.time.LocalDate`.

Try the following custom codec to make the issue gone:

```
case class Account(id: Long, name: String, birthDate: LocalDate)
object Account {
  implicit val accountFormat: OFormat[Account] = {
    implicit val customLocalDateFormat: Format[LocalDate] = Format(
      Reads(js => JsSuccess(Instant.parse(js.as[String]).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate)),
      Writes(d => JsString(d.atTime(LocalTime.of(23, 0)).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant.toString)))
    Json.format[Account]
  }
}

val json = """{"id":1,"name":"John","birthDate":"1983-02-11T23:00:00.000Z"}"""
val account = Json.parse(json).as[Account]
println(account)
println(Json.toJson(account))
```

An expected output of this code snippet is:

```
Account(1,John,1983-02-11)
{"id":1,"name":"John","birthDate":"1983-02-11T23:00:00Z"}
```

Comment: There is no need to implement parsing for such custom `Format`, can directly use [`Reads.localDateReads`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads$.html#localDateReads[T](parsing:T,corrector:String=%3EString)(implicitp:T=%3EEnvReads.this.TemporalParser[java.time.LocalDate]):play.api.libs.json.Reads[java.time.LocalDate])

Comment: `Reads.localDateReads` is less strict and allows JSON numbers as input

Comment: That's not part of the question.